# Create Email Account from CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, windows, email, plesk, mail-server

I have an ASP.Net based Community Page for Gamers.
Now the User can register there and should get an EMail Adress like the site name "xxx@mysite.com".

How do I solve this from codebehind automaticly?

My background server is a windows 2008 server with allready Pleask installed .
Can I use plesk for such things? Must I install another mailserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it via the XML API look at [this](ftp://download1.sw-soft.com/Plesk/Plesk8.1/Doc/plesk-8.1-api-rpc/28788.htm)